# Utility or opensource to implement Routing and Url-Rewriting in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, asp.net-3.5, url-routing

I need to implement Routing or Url-Rewriting in my application. So, is there any utility like logging utility Elmah. I don't want to write much code, I need to configure and start playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanna *start playing* with [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/urlrewriter.aspx)? Or [this](http://urlrewriter.net/)? Maybe not [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx), but I'll report it too because explains you the theory...

Comment: @djchelon - Thanks, I was not aware there are many things available. Let me go through these and I will come here for more issues. hope you dont mind :)

Answer (score 1):

[**System.Web.UrlRouting**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is available in 3.5.
You might also consider **[URL Rewrite IIS module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)**.